# When can preposition 'of' be omitted?

Tags: prepositions, gerunds

Sentence One: `The main image, which takes up the majority of the page, is of an artist's palette.`

Sentence Two: `These aspects are of more interest to buyers.`

It seems that in sentence two, we can remove the preposition 'of' by turning interest into a gerund. `These aspects are more interesting to buyers.` Without the gerund, the sentence sounds awkward and is incorrect. `These aspects are more interest to buyers.`

In sentence one, it seems that even without the preposition 'of', and something to replace it with, the sentence seems makes sense and is not awkward. `The main image, which takes takes up the majority of the page, is an artist's palette.`

Why does sentence one sound fine without the preposition (is it grammatically correct?), while sentence two doesn't really work without the preposition and gerund replacement?

Comment: They are two different uses of the word 'of'. However, I would suggest that it _is_ better to include 'of' in the first sentence, as an image of something is not the thing itself. There's a famous painting by Magritte of a tobacco pipe with the caption (in French) 'This is not a pipe', implying 'it's a picture of one'.

Comment: I find nothing wrong with using *of* in either sentence, and, in fact, I find they both sound better with it. Both of your *why* questions seem to be a matter of opinion. You've stated some things, but the rest is subjective. I can't determine an actual question that can be answered here.

Comment: @JasonBassford So, `These aspects are more interest to buyers.` is grammatically correct? It sounds very awkward. Why does it work without of?

Comment: No, I would not say that is correct. What I was saying is I don't see any reason to *remove* the prepositions in the first place.

Comment: @JasonBassford I agree. I am trying to explain to an ESL student who is confused as to why sentence one seems to work without 'of', but sentence two doesn't. In sentence one, if there is no 'of', it is still saying that the main image is the artist's palette. So, why do we need the 'of' there?

Comment: Note the the first sentence only works syntactically without the *of*. Semantically, it's different. (Rather than showing something that exists somewhere else, it, itself, is the thing that is used.) This, and the fact that *of* is used differently in the two sentences, was mentioned in the first comment here.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks for the explanation. That was really helpful.